# Sass/SCSS not compiling locally

Tags: css, sass

I am new to SASS and trying to compile my SASS file locally. However I am stuck at this point and have tried everything mentioned but somehow still get the same if not similar errors. Can't seem to tell what I am missing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GuRy.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile your scss from outside your project and use compiled CSS in your project. Let's say you have a `style.scss` file then compile it using below command:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Now use compiled CSS file in your project. There's no need to use node-sass this way.